# Log4j.xml throw file not found in Java EE application

Tags: java, xml, log4j

I am trying to log using log4j in my Java EE application in the following way where i have defined a log4j.xml in the application.

I am trying to access it using

```
   DOMConfigurator.configure( "src/log4j.xml");
   logger.warn( "Login Process has started a warning message" );
```

but it keeps throwing the following error

** edited error message

```
log4j:ERROR Could not parse file [src/log4j.xml].
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\src\log4j.xml (The system cannot find the path s     pecified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:79)
at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:70)
at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:161)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:208)
at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator$1.parse(DOMConfigurator.java:749)
at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:866)
at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:755)
```

When i provided the absolute path everything is working .

So whats the way to achieve this? I am using 1.2.16.jar version of log4j

and i get following warning each time i build the app

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger     (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Edited:
Application struture

```
Myapp
  src
  conf
  target
```

and i have palced log4j.xml under folder src

log4j.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
<appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p %c{1} - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
   <appender name="Log" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="Web.log" />
    <param name="Append" value="true" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{DATE} %-5p %-15c{1}: %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<logger name="com.web" additivity="false">
    <level value="info" />
    <appender-ref ref="Log" />
</logger>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Thanks

Comment: Where is the log4j file located in your application?

Comment: The currently accepted answer of Prabhat is a WTF. Renaming the extension of a valid log4j.xml file to a wrong one? Did it *really* solve your concrete problem? The answerer clearly has no idea that it's also possible to configure log4j by XML instead of by Properties.

Comment: No replacing the log4j.xml to src/resources solved the problem. and pls do mind your language

Comment: You should not accept incorrect answers. This is misleading for future readers who have exactly the same problem as you. Ask the answerer to remove/fix incorrect suggestion or post your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better put it inside `src/main/resources` folder.

You can also rename it to `log4j.properties`, depending on your file format.
And you should have either `log4j.jar`, or if you are using maven add dependencies to `pom.xml` file.

Comment: but its an xml file and its said that in the doc that it should recognize log4j.xml right?

Comment: I am also using Spring MVC... I have no problem with log4j... why don't you try to do as I mentioned earlier ...

Comment: Could you describe how you have used it in your application ?

Answer (score 1):

configure web.xml file like this.

```
   <!-- these are at the top of the xml configuration file -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/conf/log4j.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
        <param-value>api.root</param-value>
    </context-param> 

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- ... -->
```

This may help you : http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?30800-SpringMVC-XML-Log4j-Logging-not-functioning

Comment: Your error shows  that your log4j.xml file contains unparsed elements.. "log4j:ERROR Could not parse file [src/log4j.xml]"... check your xml file please

Comment: Same error does not come when a absolute path is given so i don think its an xml issue

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
DOMConfigurator.configure( "src/log4j.xml");
```

To

```
DOMConfigurator.configure( "/src/log4j.xml");
```

Comment: Still the same error persist . I will post the application structure